# why are my touch coordinates not mapping properly on screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am displaying a UIImage on screen where the user can tap and place a signature. Once the tap happens, another UIImage is loaded with the same image and a signature is placed. However what I am seeing is that where the user clicks is not necessarily where the signature is placed.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchCoordinates = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"X: %f   Y: %f",touchCoordinates.x, touchCoordinates.y);

    SignDocumentController *signDocumentController = [[SignDocumentController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignDocumentController" bundle:nil];
    signDocumentController.navigationItem.title=@"Sign Document";
    signDocumentController.sigLocation = touchCoordinates;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:signDocumentController animated:YES];
    [signDocumentController release];

}

//lets now place the image
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
            UIImage *pageImage = [PDFPageConverter convertPDFPageToImage:page withResolution:144];
UIImage *shieldLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shield_bw.gif"];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageImage.size);
        [pageImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageImage.size.width, pageImage.size.height)];


        NSLog(@"PLACING IT AT   X: %f   Y: %f",sigLocation.x, sigLocation.y);

        [shieldLogo drawInRect:CGRectMake(sigLocation.x, sigLocation.y, shieldLogo.size.width, shieldLogo.size.height)];
        [theSignature drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sigLocation.x+50, sigLocation.y) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0]];
        [theSignature2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sigLocation.x+50, sigLocation.y+ 20) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0]];



        UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [image setImage:resultingImage];
```

Adding class definition for SignDocumentController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SignDocumentController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSMutableString *signFaxString;
    NSString * messageId;
    NSMutableData *xmlData;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress2;

    NSString * annotationKey;
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSString *date;
    NSString *signature;

    CGPoint sigLocation;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
}

@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * firstName;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * lastName;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * date;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * signature;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString * annotationKey;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImageView * image;
@property(assign)CGPoint sigLocation;

-(IBAction) btnNext;


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the problem be related to the fact that you are reading touch coordinates relative to a given view, but then you are using them in another view? In such case, the relative offset between the two views could produce the difference you see... you should definitely use coordinates relative to the `UIImage` you are drawing...

Try this:

```
CGPoint touchCoordinates = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];
```

where self.imageView contains the UIImage you would like to redraw...

OLD ANSWER:

I notice that at some point you do:

```
signDocumentController.sigLocation = touchCoordinates;
```

bu then, when you draw the image you use `sigLocation` which should be some ivar variable.

```
    [shieldLogo drawInRect:CGRectMake(sigLocation.x, sigLocation.y, shieldLogo.size.width, shieldLogo.size.height)];
    [theSignature drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sigLocation.x+50, sigLocation.y) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0]];
    [theSignature2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(sigLocation.x+50, sigLocation.y+ 20) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0]];
```

I cannot find any other reference to `sigLocation`, so this variable should contain some value that has not much to do with the current location. Could be this the cause of the mismatch between touch and image location?

Comment: the NSLog statements in the above mentioned code out put the same x, y coordinates so where I click is where I am trying to place the image.

Comment: I am using the 2 different views but they load up the same UIImage in a UIImageView. One does not have signature, and one has it based on where you click. The only problem I can possibly see are the lines :  UIImage *pageImage = [PDFPageConverter convertPDFPageToImage:page withResolution:144];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageImage.size);

Comment: yeah, you are definitely not using the same image, you are getting an image from a PDF... but more to the point: is there any offset between the UIImage and the UIView where you display it and that is getting the touch? are the two image sizes (the original one, and the one where you would like to draw into) the same?